# mysqldump of latest 1000 records

Tags: mysql

how to take mysqldump of latest 1000 records from a database

Answer (score 21):

`mysqldump` has a `--where` option.  Assuming you have some sort of toehold to figure out what the last 1000 inserted records are (for instance, an auto-increment field called `id`), you should be able to tack that onto the `mysqldump` command, like so:

```
mysqldump --where "1=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000" DB_NAME TBL_NAME
```

The `1=1` is necessary because the "WHERE" keyword is inserted into the query automatically, so you do have to give it some SQL to evaluate.

EDIT: There was an anonymous edit made to this response removing the space between --where and "1=1, saying that the command errored without a space.  I just tested and it works with the space and errors without the space, unsure what the editor was seeing.

The error when leaving the space out:

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'where1=1 ORDER BY UserID DESC LIMIT 1000'
```

Comment: I did what you suggest and I upvoted your answer, but, what about integrity constraint violation?

Comment: That's a whole other problem.  My solution is a hack at best.  If you want integrity for putting the rows back in somewhere else, that's going to be a tougher problem and very dependent on your design

Comment: This has probably changed since the answer was originally posted but the mysqldump docs now say that the option should either be specified as `--where="..."` or `-w "..."` See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Comment: how to get a mysqldump of last 100 rows for EVERY TABLE in an entire database?